# Why the set membership symbol (∈) is used in formal differential privacy definition?

Tags: differential-privacy

In **The Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy** (Dwork, C; Roth, A), the formal definition of differential privacy is given as:

"

The randomized algorithm $\mathcal{M}$ with domain $\mathbb{N}^{|\mathcal{X}|}$ is $(\epsilon, \delta)-$differentially private if for all $\mathcal{S} \subseteq Range(\mathcal{M})$ and for all $x, y \in \mathbb{N}^{|\mathcal{X}|}$ such that $\|x - y\|_1 \leq 1$: $$Pr[\mathcal{M}(x) \in \mathcal{S}] \leq \exp(\epsilon) Pr[\mathcal{M}(y) \in \mathcal{S}] + \delta$$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is collection of records from a universe and $x, y$ are the databases

"

I can not understand why the '$\in$' operator is used for this definition. I mean, if they used the '=' sign instead of the '$\in$' operator, wouldn't it be the same because the definition should hold for every $\mathcal{S} \subseteq Range(\mathcal{M})$. Can you help me to understand why they use the '$\in$' symbol for formal differential privacy definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subset statement is stronger. It is true that
$$\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(x)\in\mathcal S]=\sum_{\xi\in \mathcal S}\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(x)=\xi].$$

However, if we have the statement
$$\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(x)=\xi]\le\exp(\epsilon)\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(y)=\xi]+\delta$$
for every $\xi\in \mathcal S$ and then try to develop a bound for $\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(x)\in\mathcal S]$, the best that we can manage is
$$\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(x)\in\mathcal S]=\sum_{\xi\in \mathcal S}\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(x)=\xi]\le\exp(\epsilon)\sum_{\xi\in\mathcal S}\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(y)=\xi]+\sum_{\xi\in\mathcal S}\delta$$
where the RHS is $\exp(\epsilon)\mathrm{Pr}[\mathcal M(y)\in\mathcal S]+|\mathcal S|\delta.$

This is weaker than the definition given due to the extra factor of subset size applied to $\delta$. Trivially the subset bound implies the individual output bound as subsets can have a single element.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *Your question was unclear (at least to me) until the comment at the bottom of my answer.* In that case, as pointed out in the other answer, the set subset statement is stronger: We have a bound that holds *uniformly* instead of in a pointwise manner.

The set membership $\in$ is different than $\epsilon$ which is a small positive constant used as a parameter in these definitions. So you take $\epsilon>0,$ as small as you want and figure out what the corresponding $\delta$ is for the mechanism you design to be $(\epsilon,\delta)-$differentially private.

So if $x,y$ are close to each other then we have that the algorithm outputs are close, and how close is determined by $(\epsilon,\delta)$ where in
$$Pr[\mathcal{M}(x) \in \mathcal{S}] \leq \exp(\epsilon) Pr[\mathcal{M}(y) \in \mathcal{S}] + \delta$$
$\exp(\epsilon)$ is a scalar factor and $\delta$ is an additive factor controlling how near the probability that the algorithm's output for $x$ falls in $\cal S$ compared to the probability that the algorithm's output for $y$ falls in $\cal S$ for *all* subsets $\cal S$ in the range of the algorithm.

Comment: That is actually not what I ask. I already knew the difference between $\in$ and $\epsilon$. However, I do not understand why the set membership ($\in$) operator is used in the definition instead of the equal sign (=). Specifically, I am trying to ask the reason why they use $Pr[\mathcal{M}(x) \in \mathcal{S}]$ statement rather than using $Pr[\mathcal{M}(x) = \xi]$ where $\xi$ is a specific output.